# cronjob like construction to perform heavy website jobs?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, scheduled-tasks

I need to import a lot of product feeds which takes a lot of time.
I tried setting the Server.ScriptTimeout on the importfeeds.aspx page to an hour and execute my tasks both sequentially and asynchronously.

But what I rather want is several smaller applications that I can schedule to run to perform a single task. Also because when 1 task fails, I still want to perform the other tasks as the individual tasks are not dependent on each other.

What would be the best way to approach this?

1. create single webpages which each perform a taks and schedule a call via windows task scheduler? (seems like a work around)
2. ....?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using *global.asax*.
In *global.asax*, a Method **Application_Start** is called when application start.
Run a thread in **Application_Start** method,and terminate this thread in **Application_End**。
Here is the sample code:

```
Public Class job
    Public Property StopThread As Boolean = False
    Public Sub DoJob()

        Do While Not StopThread
            If Now.Minute = 0 Then
                'Do Sync Work
            End If
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000 * 60)
        Loop
    End Sub
End Class



Public Class Global_asax
    Inherits HttpApplication

    Private j As job
    Sub Application_Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

        j = New job
        Dim JobThread As System.Threading.Thread
        JobThread = New Threading.Thread(AddressOf j.DoJob)
        JobThread.Start()

    End Sub


    Sub Application_End(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        j.StopThread = True
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You suggestion will run every time the application starts, however, I want to be able to easily schedule tasks. E.g. run all tasks on Monday morning, or run only task1 right now etc.

Comment: Application_start only start a loop thread to check task NEED to start.